# Can there exist something that subsidises that is not a subsidy

Tags: subsidies

Is the set of subsidies exactly the same as the set of things that subsidise?

Put another way: can there exist something that subsidises that is not a subsidy?

Or are there two definitions of a subsidy: the narrow economic definition, and a wider definition that includes (for example) everything that has the effect of a subsidy.

Answer (score 1):

My answer relies on two quotes. The first one:

> A rose by any other name would smell as sweet

And the second one is from the definition of State Aid by the [European Union's competition authority](http://ec.europa.eu/competition/state_aid/overview/index_en.html):

> State aid is defined as an advantage in any form whatsoever conferred on a selective basis to undertakings by national public authorities.

There is a difference between illegal state aid and subsidies, but the difference is in the "selective basis". Aid in any form that confers an advantage is aid.

Comment: I struggle to understand this answer.

Comment: That's alright, I also struggled to understand the question. If you point out what exactly you do not understand I may try to elaborate. If you find the whole answer is gibberish please consider making the question clearer.